# How to show/group 2 columns by single column in report builder 3.0

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I have a dataset with below data. I want to group Column 2 and 3 in single row against Value in Column 1. Is it possible.

From:

```
Column 1   |   Column 2   | Column 3
  A        |     X        |   1
  A        |     Y        |   2
  B        |     Z        |   3
```

To:

```
Column 1   |   Column 2   | Column 3
  A        |     X        |   1
           |     Y        |   2
  B        |     Z        |   3
```

Right now I am getting below table on RB3.0

```
Column 1   |   Column 2   | Column 3
  A        |     X        |   1
           |              |   2
  A        |     Y        |   1
           |              |   2
  B        |     Z        |   3
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a row group for both Columns 1 and 2.

Under the main design window, if you click on your table, you should see the row and column group panels. In row groups you will probably have a `details` group.

Right click the details group, add a parent group and choose `Column 2`. Once this is done right click the new group and add a parent group again, this time choose `Column 1`.

You will probably now have column 1 & 2 in multiple columns, just delete the columns you don't need and that should be it.